# Bundles on Grassmannians

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, projective-geometry, grassmannian

Let $V,W$ be two $4$-dimensional vector space over a field, $G(2,V),G(2,W)$ the Grassmanninas of planes in $V$ and $W$, $S_V$, $Q_V$ the tautological subbundle and quotient bundle of $G(2,V)$, and $S_W$, $Q_W$ the tautological subbundle and quotient bundle of $G(2,W)$.

In a research paper I read that $\mathbb{P}(Hom(S_W,Q_V))$ and $\mathbb{P}(Hom(S_V,Q_W))$ are projective bundles over $G(2,V)\times G(2,W)$.

What is the exact meaning of this? I am confused because we are taking Hom between bundles on different varieties. What is the rank of $\mathbb{P}(Hom(S_W,Q_V))$ and $\mathbb{P}(Hom(S_V,Q_W))$?

Comment: This is what I would assume. Let $p_V, p_W$ be the two obvious projections from the product to the respective Grassmannians. Then $Hom(S_W, Q_V)$ is interpreted as $Hom(p_W^*S_W, p_V^*Q_V)$. Ranks therefore are 4. Rank of $\mathbb{P}(*)$ is not meaningful, its relative dimension over the product of the Grassmannians is 3.

Comment: That's a reasonable interpretation. So the dimension of $\mathbb{P}(Hom(S_W,Q_W))$ as a variety would be $4+4+3 = 11$. Right?

Comment: Right. Not that it is important, but you wrote $Q_V$ in your question but $Q_W$ in your comment.